# do not set cookie with version below Marshmallow

Tags: android, http, cookies, get

I woluld like to make a raw HTTP GET request in Android setting custom cookie, however the code below works only with android from version 23 and later. With devices and emulators with version below 23 the code does not raise any exception but any cookie is added in the HTTP request (checked server side).

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
CookieHandler test =CookieHandler.getDefault();
HttpCookie lsd=null;

mycoockie= new HttpCookie("myc", coockie);

mycoockie.setDomain(domain);
mycoockie.setPath(path);
mycoockie.setVersion(0);
mycoockie.setMaxAge(-1);

try {
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI(basicuri), mycoockie);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

URL url;
String response = "";
try {
    url = new URL(requestURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
[...]
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I am not sure about your question. "works only with Android version up to 23" that means for 1~23 it is ok but your question title suggests the exact opposite.

Comment: [23 ~ 27 works]
[1 ~ 22 not works]

Comment: "works only with Android version up to 23" means the exact opposite. Please update your question to avoid confusion.